# What is the process of a letter between text app and terminal?

Tags: python, linux, unicode, encoding, io

The essential question is as the title describes.  And here I will provide specific scene with necessary info, and some my speculations.

[How do keyboard input and text output work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116630) This answer have talked about the topic. But here I mainly want to dive deeply into one part of it.

##### The more specific question is:

**In GUI, an Python interpreter opened in interactive mode in terminal, If I press 'A' in keyboard, then an 'a' character is displayed in screen. How exactly does app and terminal communicate ?**

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Python 3.6
- The default encoding in `locale` is:

```sh
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

- And here encoding of `setting` of terminal is `utf8`.

(**NOTE**: For terminal, I can change the encoding way in `Preferences` -> `default` -> `compatibility` -> `Encoding`, change encoding way too by changing `LC_CTYPE`. So, there are two ways to change the encoding. Through various tries, I have reason to think that `locale` is for app in terminal, and `setting` for terminal per se.)

In terminal:

```sh
$ LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.GB2312 echo 你好
你好

$ LC_CTYPE=C echo 你好
你好
```

but in Python interactive mode:

```sh
$ LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.GB2312 python  
>>> print('你好')
  File "<stdin>", line 0
    
    ^
SyntaxError: 'gb2312' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 9: illegal multibyte sequence

>>> s = u'\u4f60\u597d'  # '\u4f60\u597d' is code point of '你好'
>>> print(s)
����
```

(note1: `你好` is Chinese, [GB2312](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_2312) is an encoding for Chinese.)

(**note2**: There is one thing I should mention: the above example works fine after I change encoding of setting of terminal to `GB2312` too)

and when I change the locale encoding, some odd phenomenons appear as I type some `none-ascii` characters, where it raises some garbled characters even though I just type in command line.

Encoding is a headache all the time, so there could be more odd phenomenons in this, I can 't describe it one by one, but I try to strike a balance between brevity and completeness in example. And I glad to know the internal mechanism, I think this may clear out some of my doubts.

Here is some things I speculate:

for input:

```
           encoding it                      decode it                           
           using utf8 (by ternimal)         using gb2312 (by Python)
          +--------+               +-----+               +----------+
--------->|terminal| ------------> | pty |-------------->|Python app|
          +--------+               +-----+               +----------+
                      utf8-encoded
                     bytes sequence
```

for output:

```
    convert unicode to                      decode it  
    bytes using gb2312 (by Python)          using utf8 (by terminal)
       +----------+               +-----+               +--------+
       |Python app| ------------> | pty |-------------->|terminal|-------->
       +----------+               +-----+               +--------+
                    gb2312-encoded                              certain kind of
                     bytes sequence                               bytes sequence
```

Am I right?

And this question doesn't specifically refer to Python, merely I think using Python as example will make things clearer.

Due to I'm not clearly knowing the knowledge, so maybe it does still not completely describe things. Hope you can understand it.

Comment: What do you get if you do `LC_CTYPE=C echo 你好` ?

Comment: output `你好` too.

Comment: @Philippe According my previous speculation, the normal output in bash indicate that the characters only arrive at terminal, so it doesn't get through re-encoding by app, so things looks like everything works fine despite the encoding of `locale` changed. From this perspective, it could be explained, but I don't know if it's right.

Comment: So much of that flow is going to be outside of Python, I'm not sure it makes sense to answer the question.

Comment: What about `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 python` followed by `print('你好')` ?

Comment: @Philippe If using `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`, everything works fine. BTW, my PC encoding default to `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Python is just as a specific case for illustrating. As long as it involves communication between processes with bytes where encoding and decoding happens.There is no doubt that it makes much sense. And if you can by the way explain the above example, that would be great.

Comment: Can you see if `zh_CN.GB2312` is a valid locale by running `locale -a` ?

Comment: @Philippe I can ensure that the encoding-setting part is correct. And as in the description  updated afterwards, If I set encoding of terminal in setting to `GB2312`, then everything works fine in above example.

Comment: My point is that the layers between the keyboard and screen are so numerous and complex that this question becomes almost impossible to answer. See e.g. https://boingboing.net/2017/12/26/latency-why-typing-on-old-com.html

Comment: I have realized this problem when I write this question, So I put the line in end: `And maybe it's a 'big' question, so answering any part of it is also being appreciated`. But  I put my attention on communication between app and terminal. might as well change my title of question, that would make things much easier.

Comment: `LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.GB2312 echo 你好` probably doesn't do what you think it does. `echo` simply copies the bytes it receives as arguments to whatever is connected to its `stdout`. Nothing in that copy examines the current locale. The bytes it sees have already been assembled, and the interpretation of those bytes will be done when the bytes are eventually handled by a renderer, such as a terminal emulator, which doesn't share any environment with the bash shell in which the `echo` is executed.

Comment: My guess is same as you said. I think the string `你好` is not 'interpreted' by echo, it is a `utf8` bytes sequence all the time in process, but different in Python. So any encoding in `env` have no effect on it. I just can't prove it.